# Convert PNG to JPG with pillow

Tags: image-processing, python-3.4, python-imaging-library

I would like to convert a bunch of images with pillow (PIL for python 3) from PNG to JPG. I have explored the possibility of doing this online however it seems not to be possible. I have this script:

```
from glob import glob
import os
from PIL import Image as image
for file in glob('*.png'):
    img=image.open(file)
    name,ext=os.path.splitext(file)
    img.save('E:\\Icons\\All\\JPG'+name+'.jpg','JPEG')
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py", line 569, in _save
    rawmode = RAWMODE[im.mode]
KeyError: 'LA'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Icons/All/script.py", line 7, in <module>
    img.save('E:\\Icons\\All\\JPG'+name+'.jpg','JPEG')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1682, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py", line 571, in _save
    raise IOError("cannot write mode %s as JPEG" % im.mode)
OSError: cannot write mode LA as JPEG
```

Answer (score 1):

With the code, I did the conversion from PNG to JPEG using pillow

```
from PIL import Image
import cStringIO
from glob import glob

def png_to_jpeg():
    for obj in glob("*.png"):
        in_file = open(obj,"rb")
        img = in_file.read()
        try:
            Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(img))
        except:
            print("can not open image file error")

        im = Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(img))
        _image = cStringIO.StringIO()
        im.save(_image, "JPEG")
        store_image = _image.getvalue()
        new_obj = str("new_") + obj.replace(obj.split('.')[-1], 'jpg')
        out_file = open(new_obj, "wb")
        out_file.write(store_image)
        out_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
    from PIL import Image
    from glob import glob  

    pngs = glob('./*.png')

    for j in pngs:

        im = Image.open(j)

        im.save(j[:-3] + 'jpg')
```